# Sharing & Permissions has 2 "everyone" entries, OS X 10.10.5

Tags: macos, permission, filesystem

I was doing some stuff with the system administrator to my computer and we are not sure what we did to have this happen but we now have 2 everyone permissions in  nearly every file on my compute. The only thing we did was try to install cocoa pods and give my account the proper permissions to read-write to files application and other files. I am currently trying to run Illustrator and it says I don't have read permissions here eiher.

Edit: also if i change the everybody with a custom perm to no access it says I have read and write again but sometimes it will still say you have custom permissions above the permission area.

[image: Illustrator error]

and this picture

[image]

Comment: Have you tried repairing permissions with Disk Utility?

Comment: Disk Utility doesn't reset ACLs in the User area, hence my Onyx suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Onyx](http://www.titanium.free.fr/) - [freeware] to check/repair the disk, fix permissions & reset ACLs.

Maintenance tab > permissions, check the box at the top & Execute.

Make sure you get the Yosemite version, they're OS specific.

This will default whatever it is you did to the permissions structure... which looks a bit complex to pick through manually.