# Sharing & Permissions has two “everyone” entries, only for applications by Apple

Tags: macos, applications, permission, sharing

**OS X 10.12.6, Sierra**

My Sharing & Permissions says *"You have custom access"* and it's showing two entries for "everyone" where the first is set to "Custom".

- This only seems to be affecting every single one of Apple's applications in the Applications and Utilities folders.  I have no idea what other files are affected but a random search only turned up all Apple applications.  All third-party applications are unaffected.
- I did permissions repair using [Onyx](https://www.titanium-software.fr/en/onyx.html) but it had absolutely no affect on these applications.
- I cannot manually change permissions as the minus sign is grayed out after unlocking (see picture).  Even if I could, it would take a very long time to manually find/repair.
- I do not know what triggered this problem as I just discovered it today.  However, I recently cloned my hard drive over to a new solid state drive using [Carbon Copy Cloner](https://bombich.com).
- I've already followed [this official Apple procedure](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203538) for fixing my Home folder permissions and I don't seem to have any problems there.
- Everything appears to be operating, however, I'm seeing some strange problems like my ICC color profile will not stick after a reboot (permissions seem fine in the Library), but the ColorSync Utility instantly crashes when I click the "Repair" or "Verify" button.

[image]

I've already found and [followed this thread](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/234780/sharing-permissions-has-2-everyone-entries-os-x-10-10-5), but the answer did not help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a normal behavior of the Sharing & Permissions Info window in macOS systems protected by [SIP](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/193368/what-is-the-rootless-feature-in-el-capitan-really).

The three latter are the POSIX permissions:

```
rwxr-xr-x@  3 root      wheel  restricted   102 Jul 22  2017 Activity Monitor.app
    com.apple.rootless

rwx read/write(/traverse(execute)) for the user root/system
   r-x read(/traverse(execute)) for the group wheel
      r-x read(/traverse(execute)) for everyone
```

The first entry (everyone > Custom) is a result of the restricted flag/com.apple.rootless attribute and can be interpreted as an ACL: group:everyone deny delete **and** the ACL can't be modified!

---

An (older) list of all restricted/SIP protected files and folder can be found here: [System Integrity Protection – Adding another layer to Apple’s security model](https://derflounder.wordpress.com/2015/10/01/system-integrity-protection-adding-another-layer-to-apples-security-model/)

Comment: I had SIP disabled for a while when I posted this, and just re-enabled it now.  So you're saying that it's normal to see those "custom" permissions in Sierra for Apple's applications?  Okay then, thank you.

Comment: @Sparky Yeah, it's completely normal - and the problem you have with ColorSync Utility is not related to its sharing & permissions settings!

Comment: Thanks!  BTW, any ideas on the ColorSync Utility crashing issue?

Comment: @Sparky Is this a custom ICC profile? Probably better ask a completely new question!

Comment: No.  Open ColorSync Utility.  The "Verify" and "Repair" buttons have nothing to do with any specific profile.  The app instantly crashes when the button is clicked.   Yes, I understand about asking a new question.

Comment: @Sparky 1. First I would remove any custom profile from the  various folders 2. Then try to verify/repair the profiles again (I found/verified 23 profiles in my VM environment) 3. add custom ICC profiles one by one (4. remove ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.ColorSyncUtility.plist)